# Search engine address query

Tags: java, html

I am building a search engine using Java application. I manage to get it to work on BING

```
 String BingaSearch = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=";
 String AskaSearch = "http://www.ask.com/web?q=";
String YahooaSearch = "http://sg.search.yahoo.com/search?fr=chr-greentree_ie&ei=utf-8&type=937811&p=";
```

Ask and yahoo search are not working, can if someone can provide me with the correct query or a search engine just like bing, I'm trying to get my project to search on 2 engine instead of 1.

Your help will be much appreciated, thanks! if you have any simple to use API in mind, do share it too, Thanks!

Comment: How are they not working? What happens if you cut'n paste the URL displayed in your browser address bar?

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at the Yahoo! site they have a service called [Yahoo! Search BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/) which comes with a pricing tariff. So I'm guessing they don't want people to be able to simply make requests to a URL in the way you're trying to do. And looking at their encoded search URLs, it doesn't look like the old q= query string will work any longer.

If Yahoo! don't want you to make direct requests to their search URL, then they would likely ban requests from your application if they detected serious traffic coming from it. So I think you'll need to take a look at their Search BOSS service and see if it will meet your needs. That way you wouldn't have to worry about your application being blocked.